# Detailed report of failed fields in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to generate detailed report of failed fields in Selenium webdriver. I want to highlight the field which failed during automation.Please send me the code for that.

Comment: can you tell us what have tried so far?

Comment: @ Mrunal Hi, I got the failed page screenshot, but I want to highlight the particaular failed field in that page.

Comment: Means you want to highlight the field in Screenshot???

Answer (score 0):

javascript is the only way for that. change css attribute of that element. write javascript snippet and run it (JavaScriptExecutor) class. This should highlight the element and then u can take the screen shot.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660291/highlight-elements-in-webdriver-during-runtime)

Comment: @ Munal ,Thanks for the information. Can you please send the code.

Comment: Simple googling returned me with this url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660291/highlight-elements-in-webdriver-during-runtime. you should try searching first in stackoverflow