# Unable to highlight WebElement in Selenium using JavascriptExecutor for Firefox 35

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium

While executing the script used to highlight and reset a WebElement in selenium 2.43:

```html
public void highlightElement(WebElement element) {
  String originalStyle = element.getAttribute("style");
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) selenium;
  js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",element,
                    "color: red; border: 5px solid red;");
  try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
  js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', '" + originalStyle + "');", element);
}
```

Eclipse returns error:

```html
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: arguments[0] is undefined
Command duration or timeout: 74 milliseconds
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=35.0}]
```

Observed the issue after Firefox 35 update. Is there a workaround?

Comment: `arguments[0]`? What arguments do you refer to? This certainly has never worked. Also, please indent your code.

Comment: @Tomalak this used to work in older ver of ff. arguments[0] refers to the webelement & arguments[1] refers to the style. Visit the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660291/highlight-elements-in-webdriver-during-runtime for ref..

Comment: @Tomalak can you explain some directly executable js in a webpage to highlight a webelement? tried `arguments[0]` is web console, got 'ReferenceError'

Comment: I also had no luck with `arguments[0]`. provide your html I would try to write a javasript if you still needed.

Comment: @Saifur would like to have a universal js applicable to any html code. Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by that. But, the javascript can be different depending on the element. Provide the html if you want me to write one example for you

Comment: Elaborating.. I would like to use a unified method across my test script in Selenium. Should be able to call it any time, I want to highlight an webelement.

Comment: It's a known bug ~ https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8390. Just waiting on the next selenium release (probably 2.44.1)

Comment: @Phil Thanks! Hope they fix it in 2.44.1

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue when running with firefox 35.  I downgraded this to firefox 33, which worked for me.(https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/33.0/mac/en-US/)

Selenium server version 2.44.0 with firefox 33 resolved this issue.